# Visual Basic: How To Create a LINQ Statement for DataGridView Control?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having an issue with creating a LINQ statement for a DGV control.

**What it's supposed to do:**

When I click on a country listed from a combobox I've placed on my Form, it is supposed to act as a filter.

Example: When Brazil is selected, the DGV will then display the CustomerID, Region, etc connected to Brazil.

**The issue is, I'm definitely aware that this isn't correct.  When I do click on a country from the combobox, the DGV will only display blank spaces, or "length."**

Code:

```
    Dim Q = From Query in DSname.Customers
            Where Query.Country = ComboBox.Text
            Select Query.CustomerID

    DataGridView.DataSource = Q.ToList()
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Those tags are mutually exclusive.  Hover over them, read the words and remove the 2 that do not apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should pull each record that matches the criteria. Don't add the Select part at the end.

```
Dim query = (From cust in DSname.Customers
             Where cust.Country = ComboBox.Text).ToList


DataGridView.DataSource = query
```

Comment: Thank you so much!